# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT PNG) error

Tags: android, react-native

I have to create a splash screen and trying it according to guides
[this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/), and [this](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae).

When I create `layout/launch_screen.xml` and put there this code, it appears inside design in Android Studio correctly, but generates error

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT PNG)

Full code to `@layout/launch_screen` this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#652D6C"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch_screen"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Full error log here:

```
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref 
    (position:TEXT PNG   IHDR...@4:50 in 
    java.io.InputStreamReader@5fc473ec)     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception  
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error  
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushEntity  
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText  
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl  
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next  at 
 com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.next(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:302)   
    at 
 com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getInternalComplexColor(ResourceHelper.java:170)   
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColorStateList(ResourceHelper.java:222)   
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColorStateList(Resources_Delegate.java:262)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1017)
    at android.content.Context.getColorStateList(Context.java:621)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:65)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)    
    at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    
    at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy 
    stack to clipboard
```

Not that I have mipmap folder for pngs, and also created `@drawable/launch_screen.xml` but it seems to be unused now.

My splash for now appearing only background color but not rendering png
as it should.

Comment: I don't think that `android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon` is a vector drawable ... and we are using `app:srcCompat` for vector drawable ..

Comment: @Selvin, I changed file as you said (see above its ready). But nothing changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch_screen"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"/>
```

Comment: Why this works instead of ImageView ? Whats diff? Please shortly explain if you can. You R GR8 MAAN, it works anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

What it tells you is that the Parser has received in a possibly long text field
On line 4 in position 50 of the XML there is a strange character, possibly the character '&'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).